# Load Backgroundimage after a certain amount of time | no website load

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, web

I have a backgroundImage Slideshow on my website. The slideshow works without problems.

I would like the images of the slideshow to be reloaded after a certain amount of time. My problem is that the website keeps loading.

*When the website has finished loading, a script (slideshow.js) should be executed in the background and load the images.*

I already tried

- `<body onload="...">`
- `$(document).ready(function(){...});`
- `<script>startSlideshow()</script> (at the end of html)`

With all possibilities the page loads until all pictures are loaded

**I appreciate any hint that might lead to the solution.**

---

index.php

```
...

<!-- slideshow-->
<div class="bg-slideshow" title="Hintergrundbild">
  <ul class="slideshow">
    <li><span>Image 01</span></li>
    <li><span>Image 02</span></li>
    <li><span>Image 03</span></li>
    <li><span>Image 04</span></li>
    <li><span>Image 05</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

...
```

slideshow.js

```
function startSlideshow() {
  var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow");
  var child = parent[0].querySelectorAll("span");

  for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    child[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url("images/slideshow/p' + (i + 1) + '.jpg")';
    /*Wait 2000ms, delay*/
    sleep(2000);
  }
}

function sleep(){...}
```

style.css

```
.slideshow li:nth-child(1) span {
  background-image: url("../images/slideshow/p1.jpg");
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
  /*placeholder (replace by javascript)*/
  background-image: url("../images/foto-404.jpg");
  /*[...animation delay...]*/
}
```

Comment: What does `sleep` do? It seems suspicious...

Comment: its only a delay, a time to wait

Comment: `With all possibilities the page loads until all pictures are loaded` cause you add them through css?

Comment: i dont think so. Its either a really bad way of delaying (blocking) or it is not working.

Comment: have you tried $(window).load(function(){ // execute your script });

Comment: A more clean approach would be to load the images asynchronously in the background. This will prevent you from reloading the whole webpage just because of an image. Start by not adding the images using css.

Comment: @Tasos Fel the page loads until the script has gone through

Comment: you believe that any css delay will help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Images loaded");
  var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow");
  var child = parent[0].querySelectorAll("span");

  for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    child[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url("images/slideshow/p' + (i + 1) + '.jpg")';
  }
}, 10000);
```

The Page load normaly. With including my .js file with this code, a 10sec timer starts. After 10sec the functions start working and replace my Image Files.

With a bit more work i can load my images piece by piece and can save network data.

[Google Chrome Network stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trRZO.png)